# PEM encoded certificate is required

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to access the remote peer from SDK using Hyperledger Fabric using following code

`var peer = new Peer('Remote path', PemFile name)`

it is giving me error that
`Error: PEM encoded certificate is required.`

I have tried reading file, using string every thing. Please advise me what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 2):

This is sorted.
It should be like this
    `var peer = newPeer('Remote Path', {
pem: 'PEM file name' })`